# $color "color" is not a color in Bootstrap

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-5

If I use variables in the Bootstrap SCSS theme map, I get an Error.

My SCSS:

[image]

The Error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is theme-colors map in bootstrap 5:

```
$theme-colors: (
  "primary":    $primary,
  "secondary":  $secondary,
  "success":    $success,
  "info":       $info,
  "warning":    $warning,
  "danger":     $danger,
  "light":      $light,
  "dark":       $dark
) !default;
```

--primary-violet is not a css variable generated in bootstrap 5, in the `:root` selector you have css properties that you can use to dinamically modify css without compile bootstrap . For example `--bs-success-text`

Instead if you want access in sass bootstrap variables or bootstrap maps, you have to work in your sass after bootstrap sass has been imported and you then can access a bootstrap variable like that:

```
$my-variable: $primary
```

where `$primary` is a bootstrap sass variable and `my-variable` is your variable.
To access the map you can do:

```
$my-variable: map.get($theme-colors,"primary")
```

This does the same thing above, but it reads the value stored into the map. But you don't need to, you can directly access sass bootstrap variables.